# How to make log4j2 log itself into a file?

Tags: java, logging, log4j2

I have a file appender:

```
<Appender type="File" name="main" fileName="logs/all.log">
        <Layout type="PatternLayout">
            <Pattern>%d [%p] %C %m%n</Pattern>
        </Layout>
</Appender>
```

And root logger, configured to it:

```
    <Root level="ALL">
        <AppenderRef ref="main"/>
    </Root>
```

But log4j itself are logging into console. Is there any way to setup log4j itself logging iunto a file?

Comment: Are you talking about internal Log4j2 "status" logging (like verbose Log4j2 initialization?)

Comment: @RemkoPopma yes, exactly log4j initialization, shutdown and so on. And no, I don't want do disable it. According to the way I'm running my application I can't see console output, so I want to log it into a file.

Comment: @user12345 Please do not use code formatting for words which aren't code. [Have a look at this for more information](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/254995/4244993) *(I will remove that comment when you acknowledged it, so remove yours as well if you add a comment)*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.0/manual/configuration.html) (see sections "[Status Messages](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.0/manual/configuration.html#StatusMessages)" and "[Configuration Syntax](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.0/manual/configuration.html#ConfigurationSyntax)") you would need to set the "dest" attribute on the "Configuration" element. For example:

`<Configuration status="trace" dest="status.log">`

This will set the log4j2 status logger to TRACE level and send all its output to a file called "status.log"